# Typed in startx and now I can't log in

Tags: login, startx

I've never had to enter a password into the Pi before. It would just boot to the desktop

However, I was following some instructions which told my to type in `startx`.  I typed it in and it went into a login screen.  I tried typing in `pi` for username and `raspberry` for password and it won't let me in.

I really don't want to have to wipe everything clean.  Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Do a reboot and you'll be fine.

Comment: I already did that and it now boots up to a login screen---and it won't let me log in.

Comment: what "instructions" have you followed , i might be able to figure out what has happend. alternatively, can you type `passwd`or`sudo passwd` and change it at the terminal where you type startx ?

Comment: Can you describe the "login screen" in detail? Is it in text mode? Graphical? An what instructions did you follow?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after I messed up my .xsession-script. Rebooting wouldn't help and username as well as password were correct.

However, you can still access your Pi using SSH (e.g. using Putty on a Windows machine or `ssh pi@<yourIPaddress>` on Linux/Mac OS X) and then retrace the steps that created that mess in the first place (most likely editing `rc.local` or `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart` in a way, that the command to be executed did not work or finished after a few seconds or is executed in the background).

Answer (score 0):

press Ctrl-Alt-Backspace, Ctrl-Alt-F2 or F3, F4. Ctrl-F2 or F3, F4. If it won't give you the **text** login prompt - post here, we'll look further. If you'll have a login prompt : login, `sudo reboot` and use your Pi =)

Comment: Still didn't let me login.  I just reflashed the SD card and started fresh.